# Framelayout, Interacting with the views underneath other views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 canvas views in the framelayout, one upon another, like stack.

```
<Framelayout>
      <Canvas />    // Canvas underneath
      <Canvas />    // Canvas available to user for interaction.
</Framelayout>
```

Both canvas occupy whole area and canvas underneath is fully covered by canvas upper.
Both canvas are transparent, so user can see both the canvas(if they have any contents).

I let the user draw on the upper canvas using touch interactions.

How can I disable touch listener for upper canvas so that user will now draw on the canvas underneath, but the upper canvas still visible. Upper Canvas is just not interacting to the touch input by the user. And instead, lower canvas is interacting.

I am testing this with buttons, instead of canvas, only upper button is responding to click events. By extension same would be the case for canvas views.

I think I need some type of dispatchTouchEvent() like method. Currently it is also not working, or maybe I am using it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the touch event to the underlying canvas.

For example:

```
canvas.setOnTouchListner(new View.OnTouchListener(){

onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
    {       
        canvasUnder.onTouch(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that occured to me to, but is there not any other way. I want to just disable any input for the upper view. and all touch events to be directly taken by view underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Touch events cascade down the view tree until a touch listener returns `true`.

Since one canvas is always "underneath" another, it would make sense to make the top level canvas a child of the bottom level.  This would mean the bottom level would have to be a custom ViewGroup of some sort.

Either way, when you don't want the top level canvas to handle a touch event, just do something like this for the top canvas:

```
@Override
public void onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
   if(touchHandled())
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Then in the bottom canvas do something:

```
@Override
public void onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
   handleBottomLevelTouchEvent()
}
```

Comment: What is touchHandled()?

Comment: It's whatever method you want it to me.  It's supposed to perform an action when the user touches the View.  If it is determined that the user's touch action was not what the View was looking for, then return false to move the touch even to the parent View.  You also don't *have* to return true.  You can perform an action if the user touches the View regardless, and then return false to keep the touch even going.